# preload HTML drop down with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wanna preload a dropdown menu with data I get from a Servlet. This is how my code looks like at the moment:

```
<script>
var method = ${method};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function PreselectMyItem(value)
  {
    // Get a reference to the drop-down
    var myDropdownList = document.form.select;

    // Loop through all the items
    for (iLoop = 0; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++)
    {    
      if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == value)
      {
        // Item is found. Set its selected property, and exit the loop
        myDropdownList.options[iLoop].selected = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<body onload="init(jsonData); PreselectMyItem(method)">

<div>
            <div id="header">
            <form method="post" action="Servlet" id="form" name="form">
            <table border=0 width=100%>
            <tr>
            <td><select name="method" id="select">
                    <option value="AllDocs">AllDocs</option>
                    <option value="TermTerm">TermTerm</option>
                    <option value="DocsDocs">DocsDocs</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
                    </table>
             </form>
             </div>
</div></body>
```

The value seems to be transmitted correctly, but it's not selected in the drop down menu.

```
<script>
var method = TermTerm;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `method` variable should be a string:

```
var method = "${method}";
```

Comment: does not seem to make a difference: var method = "TermTerm"; but it's still not preselected